# Android avd manager download troubles

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

i'm looking forward to develop my own applications for android platforms and i'm currently trying to set an emulator on my PC i will use for developing my apps. However, i would like to be able to download all the packages present in the "Available packages" section but i just can't do it at the moment since my download get stuck after few seconds (around 1%).
I checked the "force https://" in the settings section but still nothing...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that the download server can on occasion get overloaded. Try downloading one package at a time; this will have a better chance of being processed from download to installation than trying to download everything before starting installations.

If it still hangs, wait a couple of minutes to give any http connections a chance to time out and then check the error log in Eclipse. It may give you a clue of what's going on.

Comment: I do not use Eclipse. I'll try what you said.

Comment: Wow. that suggests to me that there's something broken in your current installation. What environment are you using?

Comment: I'm using de GNU/Linux debian

Comment: I don't know much about what can go wrong there. On 64-bit Windows machines, you need the 32-bit Java JRE even if you have a 64-bit Java JDK installed; perhaps there's a similar problem in your environment. The only other thing I can offer is the generic cop-out advice: try deleting everything and reinstall it cleanly. Maybe someone else will have something more intelligent to offer.